# Using an NPM dependency in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I'm currently working on a help and support form, and to make it easier to handle requests I need to retrieve some information about the user's connection (ping, upload, download). Until now we were redirecting our users to a website to do the test (https://www.speedtest.net/) but I found a dependency on NPM that allows to retrieve this information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/speedtest-net

I have never worked with NPM, and despite my research, my problem remains... The browser returns the same error every time : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (which I can understand, as require is not interpretable by the browser)...
For the moment here is where I am, I'm not even sure of what I started, if someone could help me to solve this problem, it would be very nice :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Speedtest - Test</title>

        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/speedtest-net@2.2.0/index.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/speedtest-net@2.2.0/bin/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script>
            (async () => {
                try {
                    console.log(await speedTest());
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                } finally {
                    process.exit(0);
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look up "browser bundling". Two people now have suggested `require()` in the browser which does not work. It's quite annoying. You need a tool like webpack, parcel, rollup, snowpack, etc. to convert the module format to a web format. You also need to check if that package supports the browser, because not everything on npm does.

Comment: As explained above, I am a complete neophyte, would it be possible to detail your answer? On how to convert the module and check that the module will work well on browser?

Comment: Look up Parcel, It's probably the easiest to use for beginners. You basically point it at a Javascript file you want bundled and it kind of does the rest. EDIT: To be clear, my last comment's annoyance was aimed at the other two people that suggested answers that have literally never worked in the history of the browser :D Not you, OP.